# Unable to load installed module in the jade client

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Can anyone please point out why I am getting 404 error when loading the ***socket.io*** module in the client side ? I think something is wrong in the way I am calling the socket.io module in the layout.jade file.

**script(type='text/javascript', src='../socket.io/socket.io.js')**

It’s a basic express app which creates a web socket using **Socket.io** module. When I use the client( which uses Jade template engine) to connect to web sockets it throws-

```
GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Here the contents of my layout.jade, index.jade and app.js.

**Layout.jade**

```
doctype 5
html
head
title= title
script(src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js')       
script(type='text/javascript', src='/javascripts/flot/jquery.js')
script(type='text/javascript', src='/javascripts/flot/jquery.flot.js')      
script(type='text/javascript', src='../socket.io/socket.io.js') //script(src='http://'+ domain + ':3000/socket.io/socket.io.js')    
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
body
block content'
```

**Index.jade**

```
extends layout
block content
h1= title
p Welcome to #{title}
```

**Index.js**

```
exports.index = function(req, res){  
res.render('index', { title: 'Temperature Monitor',domain: 'localhost'  });
};
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
routes = require('./routes'),
user = require('./routes/user'),
http = require('http'),
path = require('path');

var app = express();
var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(httpServer);

app.configure(function(){
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
      console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.emit('welcome', {'salutation':'TMP36 Sensor output!'});      
});'
```

I ran the following command to create the app.

```
express homeAutomation
cd homeAutomation
npm install
node app.js
```

The details of my folder structure -

```
HomeAutomation
  ->node_modules
    ->express
    ->jade
    ->socket.io    
  ->public
    ->routes
  ->views
    ->index.jade
    ->layout.jade
  App.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **app.js** file is having some wrong code. Modify as below.

```
    var express = require('express'),
    routes = require('./routes'),
    user = require('./routes/user'),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path');

    var app = express();


    app.configure(function(){
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    });

    app.configure('development', function(){
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
    });

    app.get('/', routes.index);
    app.get('/users', user.list);

   var httpServer = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
   });

    var io = require('socket.io').listen(httpServer);
    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
        socket.emit('welcome', {'salutation':'TMP36 Sensor output!'});      
    });
```